# Proving identities of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $S, T \in \mathcal L (V, W)$ and $\lambda \in \mathcal F$. Let $\mathcal E = \{e_1, ..., e_n\}$ be a basis of V, and $\mathcal F = \{\mathcal f_1, ..., \mathcal f_m \}$ be a basis of $W$. Show that there are identities of matrices as following:

$[S+T]_\mathcal F \leftarrow _\mathcal E  = [S]_\mathcal F \leftarrow _\mathcal E + [T] _\mathcal F \leftarrow _\mathcal E$,

and

$[ \lambda S] _\mathcal F \leftarrow _\mathcal E  =  \lambda[S] _\mathcal F \leftarrow _\mathcal E$.

I'm having trouble setting up the matrices to prove the addition half of this proof

Comment: What does the notation $[T]_\mathcal{F} \leftarrow_\mathcal{E}$ mean?